# Primefaces inputText disabled apply style

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In inputText styleclass to set width and height when text is disabled remove border and background transparent to show textbox like label value it works in h:inputText but not working p:inputText

```
<style>
.TextField{height: auto;width: 50px;}
.TextField[disabled]{border:none;background: transparent;height: auto;width:50px;}
</style>

<p:inputText value="#{stud.name} styleClass="TextField" disabled="#{stud.fieldDisable}"/>

<h:inputText value="#{stud.name} styleClass="TextField" disabled="#{stud.fieldDisable}"/>
```

My doubt is how to set disabled p:inputText background transparent to show like label value?

Answer (score 0):

when you use primefaces components by default it uses inner primefaces css for solving this problem you should override primefaces css for more Information
look at this site
[How to override PrimeFaces CSS?](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/how-to-override-primefaces-css/)